# Is there a way I can dynamically create tables in Migradoc

Tags: c#, migradoc

I have finished creating an invoice in Migradoc. I am trying to refactor and I realize I have multiple uses of table calls with the same code. The tables headers are always the same as well as the number of columns and sizes and everything. The only thing that will change is the rows inside the table as well as the AddParagraph() text. Here is an example:

[image: Invoice Table]

I am new to c# so maybe its a matter of me using classes.. I was directed to maybe use my own class like:

```
public class MyTable 
  {
    public Table table;
  }
```

Here is some of my code for the first 2 tables I have created, it is very verbose and repeated and not DRY:

```
Table TimeDetailTop = section.AddTable();
        TimeDetailTop.Rows.LeftIndent = "-1cm";
        TimeDetailTop.Borders.Width = 0.75;
        

        Column column4 = TimeDetailTop.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(4.5));
        column4.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column4 = TimeDetailTop.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(13.5));
        column4.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        Row row4 = TimeDetailTop.AddRow();
        Cell cell4 = row4.Cells[0];
        cell4.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell4.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
        cell4.MergeRight = 1;
        cell4.AddParagraph("Invoice Time Detail");
        cell4.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        row4 = TimeDetailTop.AddRow();
        cell4 = row4.Cells[0];
        cell4.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        row4 = TimeDetailTop.AddRow();
        cell4 = row4.Cells[0];
        cell4.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        cell4.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell4.AddParagraph("Invoice Number:");
        cell4.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        cell4 = row4.Cells[1];
        cell4.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell4.AddParagraph("2000498");
        cell4.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        row4 = TimeDetailTop.AddRow();
        cell4 = row4.Cells[0];
        cell4.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell4.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        cell4.AddParagraph("Company:");
        cell4.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        cell4 = row4.Cells[1];
        cell4.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell4.AddParagraph("ADV Integrity");
        cell4.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        row4 = TimeDetailTop.AddRow();
        cell4 = row4.Cells[0];
        cell4.AddParagraph();
        cell4.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        row4 = TimeDetailTop.AddRow();
        cell4 = row4.Cells[0];
        cell4.AddParagraph();
        cell4.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        //created table of details in the invoice
        Table timeDetailTable = section.AddTable();
        timeDetailTable.Rows.LeftIndent = "-1cm";
        timeDetailTable.Borders.Width = 0.75;

        Column column5 = timeDetailTable.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(2));
        column5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column5 = timeDetailTable.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3));
        column5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column5 = timeDetailTable.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(4.75));
        column5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column5 = timeDetailTable.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(1));
        column5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column5 = timeDetailTable.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(1.5));
        column5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column5 = timeDetailTable.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3.75));
        column5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column5 = timeDetailTable.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(2));
        column5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

        Row row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        row5.KeepWith = 3;
        row5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        row5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        row5.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
        Cell cell5 = row5.Cells[0];
        cell5.MergeRight = 6;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Charge To: ADV Integrity / Error Message on Outlook   Location: NO NOT USE");
        cell5.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        cell5 = row5.Cells[0];
        cell5.AddParagraph("Date");
        
        

        cell5 = row5.Cells[1];
        cell5.AddParagraph("Staff");

        cell5 = row5.Cells[2];
        cell5.AddParagraph("Notes");

        cell5 = row5.Cells[3];
        cell5.AddParagraph("Bill");

        cell5 = row5.Cells[4];
        cell5.AddParagraph("Hours");

        cell5 = row5.Cells[5];
        cell5.AddParagraph("Rate");

        cell5 = row5.Cells[6];
       
        cell5.AddParagraph("Ext Amt");

        for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            cell5 = row5.Cells[i];
            cell5.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
            cell5.Borders.Top.Visible = false;
            cell5.Format.Font.Bold = true;
            cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        }

        //add blank row
        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        cell5 = row5.Cells[0];
        cell5.AddParagraph();
        cell5.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        cell5 = row5.Cells[0];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("04/06/2020");
        
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[1];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Beed, Jacob");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[2];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        var paragraph = cell5.AddParagraph("Service Ticket:");
        paragraph.AddFormattedText(" 41410", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell5.AddParagraph();
        var paragraph2 = cell5.AddParagraph("Summary:");
        paragraph2.AddFormattedText(" Error Message on Outlook", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell5.AddParagraph();
        var paragraph3 = cell5.AddParagraph("");
        paragraph3.AddFormattedText("Looking at her calendars in outlook, noticed about 6 or 8 \"other calendars\" and" +
            "when clicking on them received an error message that said the object had been deleted, clicked ok " +
            "and it was removed from the list. Continued to do that for all of them and clicked send and receive all" +
            "and it didn't generate the error message again. If the message returns, Wendy will reopen the ticket" +
            "including another screenshot.", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[3];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Y");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[4];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("0.50");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[5];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("125.00");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[6];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("$62.50");

        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        row5.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
        cell5 = row5.Cells[0];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("04/07/2020");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
      

        cell5 = row5.Cells[1];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Beed, Jacob");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[2];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        paragraph = cell5.AddParagraph("Service Ticket:");
        paragraph.AddFormattedText(" 41410", TextFormat.NotBold );
        cell5.AddParagraph();
        paragraph2 = cell5.AddParagraph("Summary:");
        paragraph2.AddFormattedText(" Error Message on Outlook", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell5.AddParagraph();
        paragraph3 = cell5.AddParagraph("");
        paragraph3.AddFormattedText("Remote into Wendy's computer and checked the internet calendars. There weren't any" +
            "listed. Wendy said she hasn't got the error message again but she isn't receiving emails until she logs out" +
            "and logs back in. Then, I created a new outlook profile and set it as default. The email issue should be resolved.", TextFormat.NotBold);
            
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[3];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Y");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[4];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("0.50");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[5];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("125.00");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[6];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("$62.50");


        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        cell5 = row5.Cells[0];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("04/08/2020");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[1];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Beed, Jacob");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[2];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        paragraph = cell5.AddParagraph("Service Ticket:");
        paragraph.AddFormattedText(" 41410", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell5.AddParagraph();
        paragraph2 = cell5.AddParagraph("Summary:");
        paragraph2.AddFormattedText(" Error Message on Outlook", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell5.AddParagraph();
        paragraph3 = cell5.AddParagraph("");
        paragraph3.AddFormattedText("After creating a new outlook profile, there were some of her sent emails that were missing. While trying" +
            "to resolve the issue I ended up switching between profiles a few times and the missing sent emails have returned on the old profile. I sent" +
            "a test email and it was received. She will continue to monitor for issues but seems to be resolved for now.", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[3];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Y");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[4];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("0.50");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[5];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("125.00");
        cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell5 = row5.Cells[6];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.AddParagraph("$62.50");

        //adding horizontal line 
        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            cell5 = row5.Cells[i];
            cell5.Borders.Visible = false;
        }



        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        cell5 = row5.Cells[5];
        cell5.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell5.MergeRight = 1;
        cell5.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
        cell5.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        cell5.AddParagraph("Subtotal: $187.50");

        
        for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            cell5 = row5.Cells[i];
            cell5.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
            cell5.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            cell5.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
        }

        //adding horizontal line 
        row5 = timeDetailTable.AddRow();
        row5.Borders.Visible = false;
        


        Table timeDetailTable2 = section.AddTable();
        timeDetailTable2.Rows.LeftIndent = "-1cm";
        timeDetailTable2.Borders.Width = 0.75;

        Column column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(2));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(4.75));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(1));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(1.5));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3.75));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        column6 = timeDetailTable2.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(2));
        column6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

        Row row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        row6.KeepWith = 3;
        Cell cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        cell6.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
        cell6.MergeRight = 6;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Charge To: ADV Integrity / New e-mail needed, please, ASAP   Location: NO NOT USE");
        cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;

        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Date");



        cell6 = row6.Cells[1];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Staff");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[2];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Notes");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[3];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Bill");

       cell6 = row6.Cells[4];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Hours");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[5];
        cell6.AddParagraph("Rate");

        cell6 = row6.Cells[6];

        cell6.AddParagraph("Ext Amt");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            cell6 = row6.Cells[i];
            cell6.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Top.Visible = false;
            cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;
            cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        }

        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.AddParagraph();
        cell6.MergeRight = 6;
        cell6.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
        cell6.Row.Borders.Visible = false;

        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        cell6 = row6.Cells[0];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("04/09/2020");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[1];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Beed, Jacob");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[2];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        paragraph = cell6.AddParagraph("Service Ticket:");
        paragraph.AddFormattedText(" 41466", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell6.AddParagraph();
        paragraph2 = cell6.AddParagraph("Summary:");
        paragraph2.AddFormattedText(" New e-mail needed please, ASAP", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell6.AddParagraph();
        paragraph3 = cell6.AddParagraph("");
        paragraph3.AddFormattedText("Created new email address for webinars and assigned exchange online" +
            "license. Mailbox will be available shortly.", TextFormat.NotBold);
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        

        cell6 = row6.Cells[3];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Y");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
        

        cell6 = row6.Cells[4];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("0.50");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[5];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("125.00");
        cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;

        cell6 = row6.Cells[6];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.AddParagraph("$62.50");

        //adding horizontal line 
        row5 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        row5.Borders.Visible = false;


        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            cell6 = row6.Cells[i];
            cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
        }

        cell6 = row6.Cells[5];
        cell6.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        cell6.MergeRight = 1;
        cell6.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
        cell6.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        cell6.AddParagraph("Subtotal: $62.50");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            cell6 = row6.Cells[i];
            cell6.Borders.Bottom.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            cell6.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
        }

        //adding horizontal line 
        row6 = timeDetailTable2.AddRow();
        row6.Borders.Visible = false;
```

I have created a total of 8 tables, so you can see how time consuming this is and how much code I had which was around 1400 lines. Again, is there a more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the tables look the same, just make a `CreateTable` routine that receives an array of column headings and an array of column widths.

You can define styles for header rows, odd rows, and even rows. Then you simply assign the Style property of the row instead of assigning font name, font size, font boldness, and other properties for each cell. This also reduces the code.

Comment: `Clone()` can also be used for tables that are really identical. Clone them before adding any individual contents. I think it is a matter of personal preference, but I'd rather create a routine that creates a new table each time I need one. But in our application we have many different tables with different headings, so `Clone()` is no option for us.